# Google Maps Markers - how to add content dynamically into geocode?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a problem with adding the content to Google Maps Markers. Here is my code:

```
function loadAttributeMap1() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    mapOptions = {
            zoom: 3,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(56.130366,-106.34677099),
            mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas1"), mapOptions);
    var markers = /*[[${usersCanada}]]*/; //thymeleaf access to model value
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var address = markers[i].location;
        var content = markers[i].username;
        console.log(content);
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            console.log(content);
            addMarkerToMap(markers[i].username, results[0].geometry.location, map);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

First `console.log(content)` gives me this output:

```
[Log] Jack Clinton (googlemaps, line 132)
[Log] jianing xu (googlemaps, line 132)
[Log] Po Tian (googlemaps, line 132)
```

But `console.log(content)` inside `geocoder.geocode` function returns always the last element:

```
[Log] Po Tian (googlemaps, line 132)
[Log] Po Tian (googlemaps, line 132)
[Log] Po Tian (googlemaps, line 132)
```

I want to add content to markers dynamically, and I am stuck in this moment. I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found workaround here: [Dynamic Markers - Google Maps API - Markers not incrementing with i value in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10441537/dynamic-markers-google-maps-api-markers-not-incrementing-with-i-value-in-loo)

I added function scope wrapper to `geocoder`:

```
(function(content) {
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            console.log(content);
            addMarkerToMap(content, results[0].geometry.location, map);
        }
     });
})(content);
```

And it works fine. Hope that will help somebody :)